# How do I replace [number] to {number - 1} using Regex in C#?

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I have string values like `A, something happened [1], something else [2], whatever [3]` and want to replace it to `A, something happened {0}, something else {1}, whatever {2}`.

So, basically replace `[` with `{` and `]` with `}` if there is a number between and then decrement the number between by one. Is this possible with Regex somehow?

So far I got this:

```
var text = "A, something happened [1], something else [2], whatever [3]";
var result = Regex.Replace(text, @"\[(\d+)\]", @"{$1}");
Console.Write(result);
```

However, this gives me `A, something happened {1}, something else {2}, whatever {3}`.

Is there an option to decrement the numbers by one?

Comment: [@Peter B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1220550/peter-b): Thanks for the edit, I did some wrong typing there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may decrement the number in a match evaluator:

```
var text = "A, something happened [1], something else [2], whatever [3]";
var result = Regex.Replace(text, @"\[(\d+)\]", m => $"{{{int.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value)-1}}}");
Console.Write(result); // => A, something happened {0}, something else {1}, whatever {2}
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/0Pwla0)

In case the number cannot be cast to int use `int.TryParse`:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(text, @"\[(\d+)\]", m => 
    int.TryParse(m.Groups[1].Value, out var number) ? $"{{{number - 1}}}" : m.Value);
```

For C# prior to C#7:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(text, @"\[(\d+)\]", m => {
         int number;
         if (int.TryParse(m.Groups[1].Value, out number))
         {
            return $"{{{number-1}}}";
         }
         else
         {
            return m.Value;
         }
    });
```

Comment: I will try this. I guess, that's what I was looking for :)

Comment: @FranzHuber23 If you want you may replace `int` with `long`, just make sure you use what works for your scenario best.

Comment: [@Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) I put your code into one line like that: `var result = Regex.Replace(text, @"\[(\d+)\]", m => int.TryParse(m.Groups[1].Value, out var number) ? $"{{{number - 1}}}" : m.Value);`. Of course, if the value is a `long`, I can simply use the same with `long.TryParse`. Thank you for the fast reply.

Comment: @FranzHuber23 Yeah, it will work starting with C#7, since the [`out` argument "can pass without its declaration and initialization"](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37675.c-7-0-out-parameter.aspx).

Comment: [@Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) Thank you for the additional information, I did not really look for the C# version as I'm always using the latest features but it's good to notice this to  others.